# Solr - Issue with getting highlight with hl.maxAnalyzedChars = -1

Tags: solr, highlighting

I am facing one weird issue while setting `hl.maxAnalyzedChars` to `-1` to fetch highlight for some random records, for other records its working fine.

Below is my solr query

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/core0/select?q=(text:"new year") AND (id:2343287)&hl=on&hl.fl=text&hl.fragsize=500&hl.maxAnalyzedChars=-1
```

If I remove `hl.maxAnalyzedChars=-1` from above query , or set it to some positive value (higher than text field length) , then it return record with proper highlight.

But my text field length is very long, and i want like to limit it, so I also need to set `hl.maxAnalyzedChars` to `-1` . Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

The `hl.maxAnalyzedChars` and `hl.fragsize` parameters work in tandem. If you want to highlight all occurences in a large field, according to the [maxAnalyzedChars](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.maxAnalyzedChars) documentation:

> You can assign a large value to this parameter and use hl.fragsize=0 to return highlighting in large fields that have size greater than 51200 characters.

However, as you have discovered, Solr now supports -1 as a value for `hl.maxAnalyzedChars`, to indicate analyze all characters, so I would suggest the following to highlight in a large field:

```
 &hl.fragsize=0&hl.maxAnalyzedChars=-1
```

Comment: thanks @Paige Cook for reply, i had also tried option `&hl.fragsize=0&hl.maxAnalyzedChars=-1` but that also not working :(

Comment: Ok, so what exactly are you trying to do and what is not working, I am a little confused by your original question.

Comment: For the query i pasted in my question, its returning 1 record with 0 highlights, if i just remove `hl.maxAnalyzedChars=1` from my query, it return proper highlight... 
same query with some different random id ,it return result with proper highlights. so behavior of hl.maxAnalyzedChars=-1 is causing issue, and its randomly failing for few records, hope, now my issue is clear.

Comment: and I need to find , how can i resolve this issue. without removing `hl.maxAnalyzedChars = -1` from query. as it is needed for making highlighted scan to unlimited chars.

Comment: Then I would go with setting the hl.maxAnalyzedChars to a value higher than the text field length since that is working for you.

Comment: hmm, would like to have some solution with `hl.maxAnalyzedChars=-1`. will apply it at last , if there's no other solution.

Comment: Have you tried upping the hl.fragszie to something larger than the field length to see if that helps?